# How to add coupon to WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, coupon

I am using WordPress (4.9.8) with WooCommerce (3.4.5) and I would like to add a coupon field in single product pages. I've been looking at all Woocommerce templates, but I cannot find a way to add the Woocommerce coupon field onto the product page.

Any ideas?

I don't want to use a plugin for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code will add a custom text input field for coupon in single product pages before add to cart button.

[image]

> If a coupon code is inputed in that field when the product will be added to cart, **the coupon code will be applied to cart.**

The code:

```
// Add a text input field inside the add to cart form
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_custom_text_field_single_product', 2 );
function add_custom_text_field_single_product(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation','custom_product_text_input_field', 30 );
    } else {
        add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','custom_product_text_input_field', 30 );
    }
}

function custom_product_text_input_field(){
    echo '<div class="hidden-field">
    <p class="form-row product-coupon form-row-wide" id="product-coupon_field" data-priority="">
        <label for="product-coupon" class="">' . __("Do you have a coupon code?") . '</label>
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="product-coupon" id="product-coupon" placeholder="'.__("Coupon code").'" value="">
        </span>
    </p></div>';
}

// Apply the coupon code from product custom text imput field
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'coupon_code_product_add_to_cart', 20, 3);
function coupon_code_product_add_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['product-coupon']) && ! empty($_POST['product-coupon'])) {
        WC()->cart->apply_coupon( sanitize_title( $_POST['product-coupon'] ) );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If you want to have tha coupon field **ajax powered**, It's just more complicate and too broad for stack overflow on this question, without providing any code.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect. Again, thank you.